# Magento Module Block in Admin page

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm building a module in Magento, the frontend is all setup and working and now I've got to add a page to the **Adminhtml** area (Which I've done).

The issue I'm having is that I've got my Block **(Namespace_Name_Block)**, which is all referenced in the  section of my modules `config.xml`:

```
     <global>
        .....
        <blocks>
            <veridial>
                <class>Liquid11_Veridial_Block</class>
            </veridial>
        </blocks>
        .....
        </global>
```

Inside here I've got a function

```
    public function getVeridialBaseUrl(){
        // Do Something
    }
```

Now, this function is working fine on my Frontend page with the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->getVeridialBaseUrl(); ?>
```

However, when I use this same code on my page within the **/admin** section it's not working and there's nothing in my log files from this.
Do I need to add some additional code, or an extra block for the **Adminhtml** section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this issue by using the following code:

```
Mage::getBlockSingleton('veridial/veridial');
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show much code so I'm just guessing that you didn't add your xml in the admin section. You probably have this for frontend in `config.xml`:

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <veridial>
                <file>veridial.xml</file>
            </veridial>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

You need this one for admin section:

```
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <veridial>
                <file>veridial.xml</file>
            </veridial>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't want to paste all the code and bloat the question. I've got the code above in my config.xml file

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to put the block class inside an `Adminhtml` folder?

Then the class name would be `Liquid11_Veridial_Block_Adminhtml_Veridial`

So you can call your block in layout file as belows.

```
<block type="veridial/adminhtml_veridial" name="custom.name" template="path/to/your/template.phtml" />
```

Now inside your `.phtml` file if you call any function (which resides in the block class,) it should work.